# Get the environment variable's value

Tags: java, recursion

I've written a function which can get the environment variable's value. The input parameter would one of the following:

- `${machine}/bin`
- `${machine/bin}`
- `${machine}/bin${path${OS}}/path`

I would need to check the values which start with `${}`

I've written a function which is recursive in nature, and I would appreciate it if anyone can review the code for me and tell me what can be done better:

```
private String replaceWithEnvironmentVariables(String specialChars) {
    String result="";
    boolean flag=true;
    try{
        result = specialChars;
        String temp = "";
        char loopBreaker = '}';
        char dollarCheck = '$';
        char slashCheck = '/';
        int index = result.indexOf("{");
        if (index == -1){
            result = result.replaceAll("[{},$]", "");
            return result;
        }
        for (int i = index; i < result.length(); i++) {
            if(slashCheck==result.charAt(i))
                break;
            temp += result.charAt(i);
            if(dollarCheck==result.charAt(i) || loopBreaker==result.charAt(i)){
                break;
            }
        }
        String sub = temp.replaceAll("[{},$/]", "");
        if(sub==null || sub.length()==0){
            sub="";
            flag=false;
            result = result.replace(temp, sub);
        }
        if(flag){
            String returnSub = getEnvironmentVariableValue(sub);
            result = result.replace(temp, returnSub);
        }
    }catch(NullPointerException nullPointer){
        nullPointer.printStackTrace();
    }catch(Exception except){
        except.printStackTrace();
    }
    return replaceWithEnvironmentVariables(result);
}
```

Comment: As the two existing answers indicate: It is unclear what you want to accomplish with this method. Can you provide some example input and output?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I really have a hard time figuring out what you want to archive. Maybe a working example would help me; especially one containing `/`.

So this is what I would suggest so far

```
/*
 * These variables always have the same value. Make constants of them.
 */
public static final char LOOP_BREAKER = '}';
public static final char DOLLAR_CHECK = '$';
public static final char SLASH_CHECK  = '/';

private static String replaceWithEnvironmentVariables(String specialChars) {
    // This is the only time a NullPointerException can occur inside this function - prevent it!
    if(null == specialChars) {
        return null;
    }
    // Why should result be first assigned ""? Up to the point where specialChars is assigned to result, no Exception can occur.
    String result = specialChars;
    // We need to include the $ if you are only interested in things starting with ${
    final int index = result.indexOf("${");
    if (index == -1){
        // No need to update result - just return it
        return result.replaceAll("[{},$]", "");
    }
    // declare outside loop, so we can use it outside loop
    int groupEnd;
    // start at index + 2 as we know that "${" is at index
    for (groupEnd = index + 1; groupEnd < result.length(); groupEnd++) {
        // cache char, so we don't have the overhead of a function-call each check
        final char c = result.charAt(groupEnd);
        if(SLASH_CHECK == c){
            // Don't include '/'
            break;
        }
        if(DOLLAR_CHECK == c || LOOP_BREAKER == c) {
            // Include '$' or '}' then break
            groupEnd++;
            break;
        }
    }
    // Creating temp like this will utilize array-copying-mechanics, which should be faster than appending single characters
    final String temp = result.substring(index, groupEnd);
    // "[{},$/]" is searching for too many characters as we stop, when we hit '/'
    final String sub = temp.replaceAll("[{},$]", "");
    // sub can not be null
    if(sub.length() == 0){
        // no need for flag. It is either this block or the next
        // also no need to assign "" to sub as it is never again used outside this block
        result = result.replace(temp, "");
    } else {
        // As I do not know what getEnvironmentVariableValue does, you may need your catch-clauses here. Also I would assume, that you need a return-statement in both catch-clauses as otherwise you are going to call the function with the same parameter over and over again as result is equal to specialChars at this point
        try{
            String returnSub = getEnvironmentVariableValue(sub);
            // replace will throw a NullPointerException when we try to replace with null
            if(null == returnSub) {
                result = result.replace(temp, "");
            } else {
                result = result.replace(temp, returnSub);
            }
        }catch(NullPointerException nullPointer){
            nullPointer.printStackTrace();
        }catch(Exception except){
            except.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return replaceWithEnvironmentVariables(result);
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! Your have some very good points in your answer, but mixing in comments inside the code in your answer can be a bit confusing and lead to some people thinking that you just dropped your improved version of the code.

Comment: @SimonAndréForsberg so you would recommend answers to be only comments like "don't put everything in try-catch" and "constants speed up processing"? I was hoping to be able to illustrate my points better by including a modified copy of the code.

Comment: you can always quote OP's code and criticise and elaborate as normal text. TBH I find critique in comments quite unintuitive...

Comment: What Vogel said ^^ You can include a modified copy of the code as well, there's absolutely nothing wrong with that!

Comment: Just make most of your comments to a normal text, this makes clear that you're commenting on the OP's code and not on yours.

Comment: Just for the sake of argument... I was actually able to understand @TheConstructor comments better when there were comments between code.

Answer (score 5):

```
private String replaceWithEnvironmentVariables(String specialChars) {
```

Naming. `specialChars` are no special chars, it's String in which variables get substituted. Maybe `pattern` or alike.

```
String result="";
```

Spacing. Needless assignment as it gets overwritten 3 lines below. Should be

```
String result = specialChars;

boolean flag=true;
```

Naming... `flag` means actually nothing.

```
String temp = "";
```

And neither does `temp`. A single meaningless name is sometimes tolerable (especially in short methods), but with more, it's getting harder and harder to understand.

```
char dollarCheck = '$';
```

Dollar cheque? Check? ✔? It should be a constant and called e.g.

```
private static static DOLLAR_CHAR = '$';
```

or better "variable start char" or alike. Prefer to express what it means to what it is, as the latter is obvious.

```
    if (index == -1){
        result = result.replaceAll("[{},$]", "");
        return result;
    }
```

I'd personally throw an exception for malformed inputs like `foo}bar`.

```
if(slashCheck==result.charAt(i))
```

That's Yoda style, the form `var == expr` is more common.

Now I've got lost... you parse the string somehow... OK, let's ignore it.

```
String sub = temp.replaceAll("[{},$/]", "");
if(sub==null || sub.length()==0){
```

Know your libraries. `sub` can't be `null`. Instead of `sub.length()==0`, you can use `sub.isEmpty()`.

```
sub="";
```

This line is useless now.

```
... catch ...
```

Just leave it out. Let the user deal with the problem. You may know, that e.g., using an empty String is acceptable in case of an error, but you surely don't know it *here*. Just document the exception and let the poor user deal with it. Here, "user" means you in another piece of the program.

```
NullPointerException
```

I see a single place where it can be thrown:

```
String returnSub = getEnvironmentVariableValue(sub);
result = result.replace(temp, returnSub);
```

Don't let this happen. Maybe throw a `new MissingEnvironmentVariableException(sub)`, maybe allow the caller to specify a replacement, e.g., like this

```
private String replaceWithEnvironmentVariables(
        String pattern, 
        Map<String, String> specificReplacements,
        String defaultReplacement) {...}
```

where `specificReplacements` contains the default values for missing variables and `defaultReplacement` gets used as a last resort. Allow `defaultReplacement` to be `null`, but then throw an exception if it should be needed.

Answer (score 4):

Don't catch those exceptions. In this specific case you'll get an infinite loop quite fast, e.g. calling `FOO=DISPLAY java Env "\${\\${FOO}}"` crashed with the following wrapper:

```
public class Env {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        for (String arg : args) {
            System.out.println(replaceWithEnvironmentVariables(arg));
        }
    }

    private static String replaceWithEnvironmentVariables(String specialChars) {
        ...
    }

    private static String getEnvironmentVariableValue(String env) {
        return System.getenv(env);
    }
}
```

N.b. I don't even know if that should work, but crashing like this is bad.

Answer (score 4):

Processing environment variables like this is surprisingly complicated. On UNIX type machines, environment variables are typically fairly simple because you are restricted by the shell, so that even though complicated variable names like `Th!S Is My Variable ${name}` are technically valid, they are very hard to set. On Windows this is not so hard. You can easily say:

```
SET Th!S Is My Variable ${name}=Boo
echo %Th!S Is My Variable ${name}%
```

Not that this would ever be recommended, but, it can happen.

The character-by-character parsing system you are using is also not great.

The best way I have found for doing this sort of expansion is to reverse the logic. Take all the environment variable names, and see if they match what is in your string.

If this is something you are doing 'often', then I would recommend you build a class that can handle this:

```
private static final class Variable {
    private final Pattern pattern;
    private final String name;
    private final String replacement;

    Variable(String name, String replacement) {
        pattern = Pattern.compile(Pattern.quote("${" + name + "}"));
        this.name = name;
        this.replacement = Matcher.quoteReplacement(replacement);
    }
}
```

Then, create a List of these Variables by populating it from the environment:

```
List<Variable> variables = new ArrayList<>();
for (Map.Entry<String,String> entry : System.getenv().entrySet()) {
    variables.add(new Variable(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
}
```

Now you can do that all once, in a static initializer somewhere.

Then, when you need to do variable expansion, what you do is:

```
public String expand(String input) {
    String before = input;
    String after = input;
    do {
        before = after;
        // expand each variable as it is found in the String.
        for (Variable var : variables) {
            after = var.pattern.Matcher(after).replaceAll(var.replacement);
        }
    } while (!before.equals(after));
    return after;
}
```

So, what you do is look for the possible variables in the input, instead of looking in the input for what could possibly be a variable name, and then seeing if it exists.

Now, this process will be slightly slower than what you have, but normally the environment is small (less than 100 or so variables). If you have a crazy environment, you may suffer.

Comment: For shell-like expansion you still need to expand missing variables to empty strings though.

Comment: great approach!!! but I've been asked to do search character by character :(

Comment: sorry I cannot upvote since I do not have enough reputation...

Comment: @Vineeth you may be able to do so now ;-)

Comment: @TheConstructor ;-)